# How do I break out of a nested loop in python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm triggering a loop if image **a.png** is found on the screen.

This is working, it loops until **a.png** is found, and then the **Main Find Loop** starts.

Once the **Main Find Loop** else triggers, I want to break out into the previous loop and start again.

I've tried placing a **break** where I think it should stop and head back to the first loop, but it doesn't break; the **Main Find Loop** continues.

I thought adding **break** after my else would stop that loop when the else was executed.

I'm only using the counts for testing purposes, the intention is for these to be infinite loops.

```
while CountA <20:

        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('a.png') != None:

        image_list = []
        # Get list of all files in current directory
        directory = os.listdir()

        # Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
        for file in directory:
            if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg'):
                image_list.append(file)

        #Loop through the list to find all the images
            count = 0
            while count <20:   

                #Main Find Loop
                for image in image_list:
                    name = image
                    Found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
                    if Found != None:
                        pyautogui.moveTo(1700,1000,0.1)
                        pyautogui.click()
                    else:
                        pyautogui.moveTo(1415,1000,0.1)
                        pyautogui.click()
                        break

            count = count + 1

CountA = countA + 1
```

Comment: When the main find loop breaks (the `for` loop that has "main find loop" right above it, right?), the outer loop (`while count < 20`) does indeed continue.  Are you talking about a *different* outer loop?  You have **four** levels of nested loop here so you'll need to be more specific than "out into the previous loop".

Comment: Put the inner loops into a function and `return`.

Comment: Okay well lesson one is I thought I only had two levels of loops. I was only counting `while CountA` and `while count` as my loops. With that in mind, I'm wanting to stop the `while count` loop and start the `CountA` loop.

Comment: As @samwise has suggested in his comment, you need to be more precise as to what exactly are you referring to as "out into the previous loop". I would suggest introducing a boolean value, call it maybe X, and then make it = True instead of breaking the loop. Now in the main previous loop (as you have called it), break out of it if X is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the reply you have written under your main post, this code shall work for your use-case.

```py
while CountA <20:

        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('a.png') != None:

        image_list = []
        # Get list of all files in current directory
        directory = os.listdir()

        breaking_bool = False
        # Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
        for file in directory:
            if breaking_bool is True:
                break
            if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.jpg'):
                image_list.append(file)

        #Loop through the list to find all the images
            count = 0
            while count <20 and breaking_bool is False:   

                #Main Find Loop
                for image in image_list:
                    name = image
                    Found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
                    if Found != None:
                        pyautogui.moveTo(1700,1000,0.1)
                        pyautogui.click()
                    else:
                        pyautogui.moveTo(1415,1000,0.1)
                        pyautogui.click()
                        breaking_bool = True
                        break

            count = count + 1

CountA = countA + 1
```

The idea is to introduce a boolean variable (I called it **breaking_bool**) that would tell the "previous outer loop" as you have called it to halt when it is True.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to break from the outer loop from within the inner loop is not to have an outer loop.

Since nothing really happens in your outer loop, you can replace it with `itertools.cycle` (for `while True`, since you said the counter is just for debugging), or a generator expression for limited repeats (or a combination of `itertools.repeat` and `chain.from_iterable`, but I think a generator expression is easier).

Example: Cycle though `image_list` endlessly until condition is true:

```
for image in itertools.cycle(image_list):
    Found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if Found != None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1700,1000,0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
    else:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1415,1000,0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
        break
```

Example: Cycle through `image_list` at most 20 times or until condition is true:

```
for image in (img for _ in range(20) for img in image_list):
    Found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
    if Found != None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1700,1000,0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
    else:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1415,1000,0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
        break
```

Comment: I think I have some things to think about with that now! I'm using the 1st loop to search for an image that appears only sometimes, to then trigger the 2nd loop. I can't run the 2nd loop 24/7 because I'd need to do a loooooooooooooot more work. Yourr approach I think is better longer term I think. Less loops must be better for speed I assume.

Comment: @L23P Even with `cycle` it would not run forever, since you'd still `break` from the loop as soon as the image is found. About execution speed: It does not matter if you have one or two loops, what matters is the code that's executed in those loops, and that's the same each way.